# AD locks my account

Tags: visual-studio-2005, active-directory

I had developed an application in visual Studio 2005. whenever i run that application active directory locks domain my account. I really cant understand what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell you exactly what's causing it, but here are some tips for troubleshooting.  Install the **[Account Lockout and Management Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7af2e69c-91f3-4e63-8629-b999adde0b9e&DisplayLang=en)** from Microsoft so you can get a bit more detail about the why's and whens on a lockout.

Here's an excellent article of debugging that walks you though everything and is more resourceful that me repeating it here : **[Implementing and Troubleshooting Account Lockout](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Implementing-Troubleshooting-Account-Lockout.html)**

Using these tools you can see if it's stale credentials used in your app, bad password overloads, or some security elsewhere that's being tripped by your application that your AD policies don't like.

Answer (score 1):

Is you application trying to access a network resource such as database, network file or web server?

Did you accidently hard coded some outdated network credentials (username and password)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using impersonation? Check your web.config for account info.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using authentication to a database, SSAS cube or other item that uses user/password authentication against an AD account?

If this is the case and your application tries three logins with the wrong password, AD may lock out your account (depending on its settings).  Analysis Services is quite bad for this.

Nigel.